# How to Style a P tag with a Disc

Tags: html, css

I would like to style a P tag with a disc (as though someone thinks they are looking at a list item).
I (the developer) know that I am dealing with a P element on the DOM and I do not plan on thinking for a moment that  p tag is an LI element.  2 completely different elements.  I am in branding mode right now..

Thanks for any advice!

**Update!**

I want to do this because we currenly have a good layout system going with li elements and nested p elements inside of each li.  But a project manager wants to created nested lists inside of lists and I am trying to avoid doing such as that will require more css work to handle in our branding process.

Comment: can u explain why you want to do this? or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: OP - This is a poor programming move. Lists give your code more semantic meaning. Also assistive technology provides some extra information to the user, i.e. "unordered list of 28 items"

Comment: As everybody said: **why you want to do this?** — It is a bad practice and you can resolve easily with a `<li>` tag.

Comment: What's wrong with having a paragraph styled with a disc? One thing is document structure, another is presentation. The meaning of the content might be a paragraph, not a list, but that doesn't mean I can't visually present it anyway I want.

Comment: @Telmo nothing, it's just the ...op says - we can trick audience users and blabla... | display, :before, counter, many ways to style it .

Comment: @chiefGui, I don't understand why its bad practice to style a P tag?  What if I designed a dot in photoshop as a jpeg and used it as a background image for that element?  what's specifically bad in this practice?

Comment: @RyanB how this is bad programming?  This is a branding process this involves css creativity on top of an HTML element.  I'm not converting the element, I am simply styling it in a custom way.  Please explain your point in context to my goal.  Thanks.

Comment: @blachawk Style a "P" tag it is not a bad practice — but use it for this purpose is. I mean, we have `<li>` tag which has more semantic for this purpose than a `<p>`.

Comment: @GCyrillus to answer your question, the point is to keep the HTML coding and branding and easy as possible without re-converting the entire HTML code for the sake of single initial request from a project manager.

Comment: @chiefGui Yes I plan on using the P tag for the purpose of being a P tag.  It simply has some design associated to it.  In this specific case, this "P" process is nested within an <li> element that is semantically correct and dominate within the project.

Comment: @blachawk I saw your update. For your purpose, feel free to use a `<p>` tag. :-)

Comment: @blachawk just saw your update. using `<P>` so you don't have to really code it, is still a bad call. Is `<ul><li><ul><li><li></ul></li>` *that much harder than `<ul><li><p></p><p></p></li>`? Are you not a develper?

Comment: @Ryan, its only 1 child p tag for 50 parent li tags.  Consider the math...would you create a nested <ul><li></li></ul> set, 50 times? or would you do create a simple child <p></p> set 50 times? Which would you do and why? Also just to clear up, we're talking about cosmetics on an element, not changing it behavior.

Comment: @blachawk being somebody who follows standards, and specializes in accessibility, semantics > cosmetics.

Comment: @RyanB and I respect your position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css property `display: list-item;` to make it look like a list item.

```
p
{
    margin: 10pt;
    display: list-item;
}
```

See an [example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/U5ayC/).

**Side Note:** This question spurred quite a discussion. So, just to be clear:

- Semantically

  - If the *meaning* of the content is a paragraph, use a `<p>` tag.
  - Otherwise, if the *meaning* is a list, use a `<li>` tag.
- Visually

  - Style it anyway you want. Nothing wrong in a `<p>` with a disc as long as the semantics are correct.

Comment: since you answered , we might never know why such an idea :)

Comment: What's wrong with having a paragraph styled with a disc? One thing is document structure, another is presentation. The meaning of the content might be a paragraph, not a list, but that doesn't mean I can't visually present it anyway I want.

Comment: @TelmoMarques: There's this thing called semantics, I can style the entire website with divs, that does not make it a good website. There's a reason we have tags for different purposes.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, and you are confusing the issue of semantics with presentation. If an item is a P it should be marked up as a P, and if the designer is so perverse as to want to make it look like an LI, that's his or her business, as long as it is marked up as and functions like a P.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha a paragraph styled with a disc is still a paragraph. That's what I'm trying to say. A bad practice would be to change a `<p>` for a `<li>` just because of a visual property, when the meaning of the content isn't a list.

Comment: exactly what was looking for.  don't know why there are so many haters on here!

Comment: ALL!!! I will still treat the element as a P tag based on the DOM, but for visual purposes, some people around the office get emotionally excited when they see the little dot next to the text.  They do not know the complexity of how the branding process is built, which is why I am trying to make both my needs and their needs met with this one shot.  Thank you Telmo!